# How does the element of DOM work? Is it a kind of pointer?

Tags: javascript, sorting, dom

I got a problem when I tried to sort the title alphabetically in my small project. There is a variable "sortedRows", which stores the sorted rows after using "sort" function. The webpage is listed below.

[image: Before sorting]

```
function sortTitle(){
    const rows = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".tbody")); # get the table rows
   
    const sortedRows = rows.sort((a, b) => {

        const aText = a.querySelectorAll("td")[1];
        const bText = b.querySelectorAll("td")[1]; 

        if(aText.textContent > bText.textContent){
            return -1;
        }

        if(aText.textContent.toLowerCase() < bText.textContent.toLowerCase()){
            return 1;
        }

        return 0;
    })

    const newRows = document.getElementsByClassName("tbody"); 


    for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){

        console.log(sortedRows[i].innerHTML); # I tried to replace the rows with sortedrows, but here is an error. The test1 and dwc did not swap


        newRows[i].innerHTML = sortedRows[i].innerHTML; 
     
    }


  };
```

The error will be like:
[image: after sorting]

Before the for loop in the code chuck, I found the sortedRows[0] is dwc and sortedRows[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5y8oE.png) is test1, however, in after the for loop, both sortedRows[0] and sortedRows[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5y8oE.png) are dwc. I am not sure what happened when I tried to "newRows[i].innerHTML = sortedRows[i].innerHTML;". I will be appreciated if anyone can help me find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the ability to test your code, but I can suggest that instead of trying to replace the elements of newRows inside of the for loop you can use something like this:

```js
newRows = [...sortedRows];
```

In JS this is called spread operator. Using it like this with one dimension array is beneficial to make a shallow copy.
In a nutshell, using this you can clone the entire content of sortedRows into new Rows. You may find this article of [FreeCodeCamp interesting:](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-clone-an-array-in-javascript-1d3183468f6a/).

Comment: Hi, I tried to use this code. But it still does not work. Seem like I need to find a way to assign values to actual DOM object. The problem is, the sorted row("test1", "dwc") will change to ("dwc", "dwc") when I tried to replace the innerHTML contents.

Comment: Hey, sorry I make mistake when I told you to try to do this inside of the for loop. It should be outside the for loop.

Comment: I know it should be outside of the loop. The question is , the nedRows is copied from the sortedRows, and this element did not change the html contents.